# Regex for phone number analog

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

I have a string: `+0 000 000-00-00`

And we need find all "border" zero and add `[` or `]` symbol, for exmple out string must see this:

`+[0] [000] [000]-[00]-[00]`

In this time i use several `String.replace()` function:

```
val stringBuilder = StringBuilder(maskFormat
                .replace("+0", "+[0")
                .replace(" 0", " [0")
                .replace("0 ", "0] ")
                .replace("-0", "-[0")
                .replace("0-", "0]-")).append("]")
```

and i think this is not optimally.

How can write regex for such transformations replace one (or two if over time it is impossible)?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer contains a working solution, and drop a line if anything is unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Very grateful for the help! Regex is what I need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match 1+ digits using a mere `\d+` regex and wrap them with `[...]` using

```
"+0 000 000-00-00".replace(Regex("""\d+"""), "[$0]") // => +[0] [000] [000]-[00]-[00]
```

See the [Kotlin demo online](https://ideone.com/UuysIt). The `$0` inside the replacement string is a placeholder that refers to the whole match value found by the regex engine.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rCN6G0/1).

If you really mean to only wrap blocks of `0`s with `[...]` use

```
 .replace(Regex("""\b0+\b"""), "[$0]")
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rCN6G0/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `0+` - 1+ `0` chars
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Using `"""\b\d+\b"""` you will match any 1+ digit chunk as a whole word.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with a simple ["word boundary"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) surrounding a series of digits:

```
\b(\d+)\b -> [$1]
```

Which yields:

```
+0 000 000-00-00 // +[0] [000] [000]-[00]-[00]
+0 867 5309      // +[0] [867] [5309]
```

Comment: the question isn't about border 0 ? only 0 must be replaced by `[0` or `0]`, no ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis Yes, re-reading the question I see that my initial assumption that the mask was simply presented as a _format_ may be misguided. In that case `\b(0+)\b` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about border 0, so this regex should do the trick:

```
"+0 000 000-00-00".replaceAll( "([ \\-+])0", "$1[0")  // border left
                  .replaceAll( "0([ \\-+])", "0]$1"); // border right
```